# Open a connexion-based REST service with gunicorn

Tags: python-3.x, rest, gunicorn, python-3.9, connexion

I have a Flask service built with [connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The service is initialized in a function `create_app()` that is defined in the script `src/group/application/my_service/api/app.py` :

```
# app.py
def create_app():
   arguments = {"url": "0.0.0.0"}
   app = connexion.App(__name__, options={"swagger_ui": True})
   app.add_api("openapi-spec.yml", arguments=arguments, strict_validation=True)
   app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

In `src/group/application/my_service/__main__.py`, I import `create_app` and execute it:

```
# __main__.py
from group.application.my_service.api.app import create_app
create_app()
```

With this in place, I can successfully open the service with python :

```
python -m src.group.application.my_service
```

I would like now to use [gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/) instead. I am trying the following command

```
gunicorn -w 1 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 'src.group.application.my_service.api.app:create_app()'
```

but I am getting the following error message :

```
[2021-05-19 11:55:32 +0200] [13275] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2021-05-19 11:55:32 +0200] [13275] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (13275)
[2021-05-19 11:55:32 +0200] [13275] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-05-19 11:55:32 +0200] [13276] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13276
 * Serving Flask app "src.group.application.my_service.api.app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
2021-05-19 11:55:33,672 [CRITICAL] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/repo_name/src/group/application/my_service/api/app.py", line 39, in create_app
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
  File "/Users/user/venvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/connexion/apps/flask_app.py", line 96, in run
    self.app.run(self.host, port=self.port, debug=self.debug, **options)
  File "/Users/user/venvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/Users/user/venvs/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1030, in run_simple
    s.bind(server_address)
OSError: [Errno 48] Address already in use

Failed to find application object: 'create_app()'
[2021-05-19 11:55:33 +0200] [13276] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13276)
[2021-05-19 11:55:33 +0200] [13275] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-05-19 11:55:33 +0200] [13275] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
```

How can I successfully open the service with Gunicorn, and without having the warning message about the fact that I am in a development service (which is the root cause why I want to use gunicorn) ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the function `creat_app()` should return `app` instead of calling `app.run()`